# Prioritizing methods that have to be run on a Timer

Tags: algorithm

This question is not about any specific language, it's rather solving a problem.

I have a timer that sends a method to a robot and asks for sensor data.

Some sensors are really critical and should be almost always be requested while some other sensors are not that critical but should be read from time to time.

So imagine I have my timer and in the timer it asks for a method that will be returned by the code below:

```
Timer_Tick()
{
   AskForData(SensorRequestList())
}

private int _tCliffState = 0;
private int _tCliffSignal = 0;
private int _tLight = 0;
//and 7 other 

private byte[] SensorRequestList()
{
    if (_tCliffState <= 5)
    {
        _tCliffState++;
        return RequestCliffStates();
    }
    if(_tCliffSignal < 1)
    {
        _tCliffSignal++;
        return RequestCliffSignals();
    }
    if(_tLight < 1)
    {
        _tLight++;
        RequestLightSignals();
    }
    //and more ifs!


    //reset all
    _tCliffState = 0;
    _tCliffSignal = 0;
    _tLight = 0;
    //...
}
```

What is the best way if I have 10 methods, lets say named like 1,2,3,...10 and also priority is like 1,2,3...10.

How can I achive a nice pattern that I can be sure that methods with more priority will requested more? something like this pattern:

`1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,4 and so on`

Comment: What is a method? Redefining the meaning of method is making it a bit difficult for me to understand the question. Code snippet doesn't show anything 'sent' but in the description, you said methods are sent - do you mean the byte[] is set of methods?

Comment: No, `byte[]` is just the serial command array that will be sent to serial port...has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Then my question still stands - what does it mean when you say "timer that sends a method to a robot"?  I have always saw a method as a verb and not data.

Comment: @MuraliP `AskForData()` sends a method that has been returned from `SensorRequestList()` and `SensorRequestList()` will choose from the methods that contain serial byte of the command for specific sensors as theire name suggests.

Comment: I don't understand the pattern you've given. Do you want a specific pattern or randomized sequence conforming to a certain frequency distribution?

Comment: @mikez Well that pattern is just an example, but you can see the method `1` should be selected more than others.

Comment: You need to read about soft realtime systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with counter techniques like the one you are using is that at a given time you may have more than one *method* eligible for execution. On solution to mitigate the problem is to stop the counter, queue all the qualified *methods*, and select each queued one for the next timer events, until the queue is empty. Once empty, you can restart the counting process to select a new set of *methods*.

Here is a possible implementation (untested code), using an `int` to store the *methods* queue:

```
Timer_Tick() {
   AskForData(SensorRequestList());
}

private int _state[NUM_METHODS]; // initialized to 0
private int _priority[NUM_METHODS]; 
private int _flags; // initialized to 0
private (byte [])(*_methods)[NUM_METHODS]; // array of pointer to functions, 
                                                                            // runnables, etc.


private byte[] SensorRequestList() {
     do {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_METHODS; ++i)
            if ((1 << i) & _flags){
                _flags &= ~(1 << i);
                _state[i] = 0;
                return _method[i]();
           }

         for (i = 0; i < NUM_METHODS; ++i){
            _state[i]++;
            _flags |= (_state[i] >= _priority[i]) << i;
        }
    } while (!_flags);
}
```

This implementation requires the number of *methods* to be smaller than `sizeof(int) * 8` of the platform (assuming 8bit per byte). It could be easily switched to using a real queue for a larger number.

Alternatively to the resetting of `_state` to `0`, one could use the following:

```
  _state[i] -= _priority[i];
```

and keep the counters rolling, but this would certainly require much more care in how selected elements are queued.

Comment: function fixed to always return a selection.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to analyze data collected over a period of time if the data comes in regularly - e.g. once a millisecond, once a second, once a day, once a week or whatever.

If you end up needing to guarantee performance - perhaps the robot will make a mistake if it does not hear from some sensor at least every second or something - it will be easier if your program runs on some sort of regular schedule.

For these reasons, I suggest that you collect your data by repeatedly making some fixed number of requests, with a fixed inteval between each fixed number of requests. I would normally call such a fixed number of requests a frame.

Give very important sensor readings their own slot in the frame, so that they are collected every frame. Have less important sensor readings share a slot between them, so you could, for example, have 8 sensor readings sharing a single slot, each collected once every 8th frame. If you want to make life more complicated, you can share sub-slots, so 8 really unimportant sensor readings could share a sub-slot, and each be collected once every 64 frames.

It is generally a good idea to keep some sort of timestamp with the data as well as the raw values. In fact, some systems arrange to take a snapshot every frame and record the time of this snapshot, and then read the values out after the time of the snapshot. Then all the values are readings taken at the same instant, and this instant is known.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a description of pseudocode of a heuristic that should give you something reasonable.

1. Add together all priorities, and call it sum.
2. Sort the list by priority, in descending order.
3. Initialize an empty array of size sum.
4. Starting with the first (highest priority) element, add as many instances of it to the list as its priority. When choosing the spacing, take wrap-around into account.
5. Continue with lower-priority elements, considering only free spaces in the array.
6. After t ticks, request sensor data corresponding to position t % sum in the array.

Using your example with 10 unique elements A..J with priorities 1..10, we get sum = 55, and our array is [A, B, C, D, E, A, C, B, F, G, A, D, C, B, E, A, H, F, C, B, A, D, E, G, C, A, B, I, D, E, A, C, B, F, H, A, D, C, B, E, A, G_, F, C, B, A, D, E, I, G, B, D, F, H, J], which seem reasonably well-distributed according to what you need.